# Update running animation in Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

I am doing a spinning animation after an action on a button. But to know where the animation needs to stop (the final angle) I need to do a call to backend. So I start the animation and when I receive the response from the backend I update the animation. Here is the code :

```
const anim = scene.tweens.add({
    targets: [targetContainer],
    angle: angle,
    duration: WHEEL_ROTATION_DURATION,
    ease: 'Cubic.easeOut',
})
```

And the update :

```
anim.data[0].end += newAngle
```

It works properly but the moment the angle is updated the animation produce a "glitch/jump" that is not nice to see.
Any idea on how to make it smooth ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Antriel on phaser forums :

> Best way to make it smooth would be to manually update the angle in
> update, using constant speed (so something like container.angle +=
> angleSpeed * dt). Then afterwards, when you get the backend response,
> just start the easeOut tween with the correct end position, and
> specify speed rather than the duration.

Works very well.